# Dynamically extend Spring REST interface at runtime

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, runtime

I want to build an application with REST interface using Spring. The interface must be extendable at runtime: The application extends the Interface dynamically depending on unknown configuration. This configuration may change with time.

For example I have a Rest interface at http://domain.com/rest. The interface has a REST item at */rest/item which supports POST to create a new REST method. Calling POST on this REST item leads to an extension of the interface regarding to parameters given in POST request (e.g item name, properties, allowed operations (GET POST) and the code which is called by those operations). This may lead us to a new REST item at */rest/newItem.

Since I only found Spring examples using a static XML config I'm wondering...

Is this possible with spring?
Any example to quickstart this approach?

Comment: So you're asking how to build an unknown interface which will change in unknown ways? Unfortunately,  in its current form,  this question is so incredibly broad, that I'm not sure it's feasible to provide valid answers. All I can say is that Spring wouldn't prevent you from creating a dynamic REST interface.

Comment: The question is not clear at all.

Comment: Sry for not beeing clear enough. I added some more details to the question. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely can have dynamic URL structure with Spring MVC. Take a look at [path patterns](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-patterns). In such case you would have one request mapping with path pattern (e.g. `@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/*")`) and your dynamic logic.